# What is a simple ratio in which atoms combine?

Tags: stoichiometry

According to Modern Atomic Theory:

> The ratio in which the different atoms combine may be fixed and integral but may not always be simple.

The example given is that in sugar molecule the ratio of $\ce{C,H}$ and $\ce{O}$ atoms is $12:22:11$ *which is not simple*.

Well, what I see here is that 12,22 and 11 are whole numbers, then why is this *not* a simple ratio?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ratio of C, H and O atoms of 12:22:11 is likely to be sucrose. Glucose has a simpler ratio of 1:2:1 (even though it has 6 carbons). The usual context for presenting the theory is with inorganic compounds with no more than a 2:3 or 3:5 ratio. With this limitation, they use the words simple ratio since the numbers are small and can easily be found. The ratio of 12:22:11 could be confused with another ratio if your calculations are off by 20%.

Answer (score 2):

It is often not true within inorganic chemistry (isomorphous substitution, fractional valences; e.g., ruby, sapphire).  Discrete organics are overall exact single compositions.  Polymers are not.  Hydrocarbons have simple empirical formulas.  Add heteroatoms and all bets are off.

Hemoglobin is $\ce{C2952H4664O832N812S8Fe4}$. Every high molecular weight Kraton thermoplastic elastomer triblock polymer contains a single atom of silicon at its exact middle.  Plasma-drawn Spectra ultra-high molecular weight gel-crystallized polyethylene, some 20 times by weight stronger than steel cable, is $\ce{CH2}$.

[Dicoronylene](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dicoronylene): $\ce{C48H20}$
[Bacitracin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bacitracin): $\ce{C66H103N17O16S}$